# Installing EntityFramework 6.1.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am getting the following error when installing Entity Framework with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition:

> install-package EntityFramework Attempting to gather dependency
>   information for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with respect to
>   project 'Vidly', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' Attempting
>   to resolve dependencies for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with
>   DependencyBehavior 'Lowest' Resolving actions to install package
>   'EntityFramework.6.1.3' Resolved actions to install package
>   'EntityFramework.6.1.3' Adding package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to
>   folder '\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages' Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to
>   folder '\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages' Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to
>   'packages.config' Executing script file '\\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\init.ps1'
>   Executing script file '\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1'
>   Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load
>   file or assembly 'file://\\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityF
>   ramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation
>   is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" At
>   \\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:62
>   +     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At \\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio\2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:50
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or
>   assembly 'file://\\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\too
>   ls\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" At
>   \\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809
>   char:31
>   +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException   Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or
>   assembly 'file://\\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityF
>   ramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation
>   is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" At
>   \\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:62
>   +     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At \\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:50
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or
>   assembly 'file://\\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\too
>   ls\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" At
>   \\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809
>   char:31
>   +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

I have tried bricelam's solution [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1950), but neither replacing the psm1 file nor copy-pasting the text works, and produces the following:

> Import-Module : File \\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1
>   cannot be loaded. The file \Mac\Home\Documents\Visual St udio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1
>   is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system.
>   Please see "get-help about_signing" for  more details.. At
>   \\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Vidly\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\init.ps1:8
>   char:14
>   + Import-Module <<<<  (Join-Path $toolsPath EntityFramework.psd1)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

This is all in an effort to run enable-migrations, which, naturally, failed.

If it matters, I am running Windows 7 x64 using Parallels on a MacBook Pro.

**EDIT**
Mark Sowul's answer below points to the fact that using a network share, a Parallel's feature, would cause this issue. I am unsure how to change the directory, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to move my \Visual Studio 2015 folder with the \Projects subfolder. In my case I moved it to C:\, which cleared up all issues.

Answer (score 2):

You're running against a network share (\\mac).  Try running it against a local directory.  As part of the nuget package installation, it is trying to run a powershell script.  For security reasons, by default, remote scripts across the network will not be executed.

Note that stackoverflow is escaping the double-slash in the original post, and I had to put in four slashes to get it to show up properly here.

Comment: I had a hunch that was it. Pardon my ignorance, but how can I run it against a local directory using the Packet Manager?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with parallels to answer that question